# Create a simple Bootstrap Yes/No confirmation or just notification alert in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

It's so simple in a non-Angular environment. Just html and a two line of js code to show a modal confirmation dialog on the screen.

Now I am developting an AngularJS project in which I am using ui-bootstrap modal confirmation dialogs all over the place and I am sick of creating new controllers even for simple things like "Are you sure to delete this record?" kind of stuff.

How do you handle these simple situations? I am sure some people wrote some directives to simplify the needs.

I am asking you to share your experiences or the projects you know about that subject.

Comment: This implementation would help you  https://github.com/m-e-conroy/angular-dialog-service

Comment: @Chandermani looks good. Going through the docs right now, thanks!

Comment: @Chandermani that implementation also requires creating an additional controller which doesn't answer my needs.

Comment: Look at v1 codepen http://codepen.io/m-e-conroy/pen/rkIqv, for dialog of type error, notify and confirm

Comment: @Chandermani, Missed that one, I see your point now :)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

so create a reusable service for that... [read here](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/building-an-angularjs-modal-service)

code here:

```
angular.module('yourModuleName').service('modalService', ['$modal',
// NB: For Angular-bootstrap 0.14.0 or later, use $uibModal above instead of $modal
function ($modal) {

    var modalDefaults = {
        backdrop: true,
        keyboard: true,
        modalFade: true,
        templateUrl: '/app/partials/modal.html'
    };

    var modalOptions = {
        closeButtonText: 'Close',
        actionButtonText: 'OK',
        headerText: 'Proceed?',
        bodyText: 'Perform this action?'
    };

    this.showModal = function (customModalDefaults, customModalOptions) {
        if (!customModalDefaults) customModalDefaults = {};
        customModalDefaults.backdrop = 'static';
        return this.show(customModalDefaults, customModalOptions);
    };

    this.show = function (customModalDefaults, customModalOptions) {
        //Create temp objects to work with since we're in a singleton service
        var tempModalDefaults = {};
        var tempModalOptions = {};

        //Map angular-ui modal custom defaults to modal defaults defined in service
        angular.extend(tempModalDefaults, modalDefaults, customModalDefaults);

        //Map modal.html $scope custom properties to defaults defined in service
        angular.extend(tempModalOptions, modalOptions, customModalOptions);

        if (!tempModalDefaults.controller) {
            tempModalDefaults.controller = function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
                $scope.modalOptions = tempModalOptions;
                $scope.modalOptions.ok = function (result) {
                    $modalInstance.close(result);
                };
                $scope.modalOptions.close = function (result) {
                    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                };
            };
        }

        return $modal.open(tempModalDefaults).result;
    };

}]);
```

html for display

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <h3>{{modalOptions.headerText}}</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <p>{{modalOptions.bodyText}}</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn" 
          data-ng-click="modalOptions.close()">{{modalOptions.closeButtonText}}</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" 
          data-ng-click="modalOptions.ok();">{{modalOptions.actionButtonText}}</button>
</div>
```

once this is done... you just have to inject above service whereever you want to create a dialog box, example below

```
 $scope.deleteCustomer = function () {

    var custName = $scope.customer.firstName + ' ' + $scope.customer.lastName;


    var modalOptions = {
        closeButtonText: 'Cancel',
        actionButtonText: 'Delete Customer',
        headerText: 'Delete ' + custName + '?',
        bodyText: 'Are you sure you want to delete this customer?'
    };

    modalService.showModal({}, modalOptions)
        .then(function (result) {
             //your-custom-logic
        });
}
```

Comment: This looks like an elegant way of using dialogs globally. Will wait for other answers before accepting your answer by the time I give a go for this. Thanks!

Comment: I am using this approach in my application at the moment. Also, appreciate the link for Dan Wahlin's blog post. Marking your suggestion as the answer.

Comment: How can you close this modal from code? I mean automatically when some proccess finished. Trigger on close button doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: give me the link to your question, will put the necessary code an answer

Comment: To be able to use this modal, one has to do the following: 1. Load `ui-bootstrap-0.14.3.js` (or the appropriate file version) in index.html 2. Declare `ui.bootstrap` as a dependency for the app, like so: `angular.module('testApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);`. If including latest version, in the above code for the Modal Service, replace `$modal` with `$uibModal` and replace `$modalInstance` with `$uibModalInstance`.

Comment: This is a great example, I searched for hours for such thing

Comment: Here controller is taking the decision of displaying modal popup. As modal is a kind of view, is it appropriate to display it from controller?

Comment: anyone has a problem with unknown provider aProvider after uglify?

Comment: I tried to use to stop user from leaving page but leaved page anyway and after leaving page show modal.

Comment: Having this error message in console after execution of this row in code : return $modal.open(tempModalDefaults).result;

Error : Unknown provider: aProvider <- a

Answer (score 17):

You can see my example. whatever i'v done.

```
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="firstCtrl">
    <button ng-click="delete(1);">Delete </button>
  </div>
```

script

```
 var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
 app.controller('firstCtrl', ['$scope','$window', function($scope,$window) {
  $scope.delete = function(id) {
    deleteUser = $window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the Ad?');
    if(deleteUser){
     //Your action will goes here
     alert('Yes i want to delete');
    }
  };
 }])
```

Comment: I guess you missed the part "Bootstrap Modal Dialogs" :) Thanks for the answer, though...

Answer (score 13):

You can use the [Angular Confirm](https://github.com/jameskleeh/angular-confirm/tree/1.2.x) library.

When included, it's became available as a directive:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="delete()" confirm="Are you sure?">Delete</button>
```

As well as a service:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
  .controller('MyController', function($scope, $confirm) {
    $scope.delete = function() {
      $confirm({text: 'Are you sure you want to delete?', title: 'Delete it', ok: 'Yes', cancel: 'No'})
        .then(function() {
          // send delete request...
        });
    };
  });
```

Comment: Thanks! Good to know that :)

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: Thanks @walla, fixed!

Answer (score 6):

For anything that has code that is triggered with a ng-click I just add a confirm attribute

eg

```
<a confirm="Are you sure?" ng-click="..."></a>
```

and confirm comes from (not mine, found on the web)

```
app.controller('ConfirmModalController', function($scope, $modalInstance, data) {
        $scope.data = angular.copy(data);

        $scope.ok = function() {
            $modalInstance.close();
        };

        $scope.cancel = function() {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };
    }).value('$confirmModalDefaults', {
        template: '<div class="modal-header"><h3 class="modal-title">Confirm</h3></div><div class="modal-body">{{data.text}}</div><div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button><button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button></div>',
        controller: 'ConfirmModalController'
    }).factory('$confirm', function($modal, $confirmModalDefaults) {
        return function(data, settings) {
            settings = angular.extend($confirmModalDefaults, (settings || {}));
            data = data || {};

            if ('templateUrl' in settings && 'template' in settings) {
                delete settings.template;
            }

            settings.resolve = { data: function() { return data; } };

            return $modal.open(settings).result;
        };
    })
    .directive('confirm', function($confirm) {
        return {
            priority: 1,
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                confirmIf: "=",
                ngClick: '&',
                confirm: '@'
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                function reBind(func) {
                    element.unbind("click").bind("click", function() {
                        func();
                    });
                }

                function bindConfirm() {
                    $confirm({ text: scope.confirm }).then(scope.ngClick);
                }

                if ('confirmIf' in attrs) {
                    scope.$watch('confirmIf', function(newVal) {
                        if (newVal) {
                            reBind(bindConfirm);
                        } else {
                            reBind(function() {
                                scope.$apply(scope.ngClick);
                            });
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    reBind(bindConfirm);
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

My google FOO has failed me and I cannot find the source site for this. I will update if I find it.

Comment: Simple and understandable. Will try that as soon as I have time. Thanks, @Steve Drake

Comment: thanks, I am new(ish) to angular and I find that there are so many ways todo things, I picked this one as I liked the fact that you just have a attribute and of you go, you can also have a confirmif attribute that returns a bool.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a simple factory like this

```
angular.module('app')
.factory('modalService', [
    '$modal', function ($modal) {
        var self = this;
        var modalInstance = null;
        self.open = function (scope, path) {
            modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: path,
                scope: scope
            });
        };

        self.close = function () {
            modalInstance.dismiss('close');
        };
        return self;
        }
]);
```

In your controller

```
angular.module('app').controller('yourController',  
  ['$scope','modalService',function($scope,modalService){

$scope.openModal=function(){
 modalService.open($scope,'modal template path goes here');
 };

$scope.closeModal=function(){
 modalService.close();
//do something on modal close
 };
 }]);
```

I have passed `$scope` in service function so that you can access closeModal function and in case you want to access some data from your controller .
In your html

```
<button ng-click="openModal()">Open Modal</button>
```

Comment: Simplified version of what @entre suggested. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: And how this solution handle if I click yes or not in confirmation modal window?