# angularjs DELETE FUNCTION ask the client if he is sure to delete

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, confirm

*Hey i have a delete function works on http:*

```
$scope.RemoveWorker=function(workerid){
    $http.delete("/ShiftWeb/rest/admin/removeworker?id="+workerid)
            .then(function(response){$scope.removeworker=response.data;
            alert("Worker " + workerid + " Deleted");
            $state.reload()
            console.log(response.data);
            }, function(error) {
                alert(error.data);
            }
            );
};
```

**anybody knows how do i ask the client if he sure he wants to delete it or not. if he say no then dont delete it.
help please :)**

Comment: Use [ui.bootstrap.modal](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!modal). But be aware modal dialogs can double error rates, increase time to task completion, and are near-universally despised by users. Alternate means of notification are often available and should be utilized wherever possible and appropriate. [ref](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12637/what-research-is-there-suggesting-modal-dialogs-are-disruptive)

Comment: See [MDN Web API Reference - Window.confirm()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm)

Comment: Kamlesh was way easier xD but ty!

Comment: Kamlesh's way is easier, but george's suggestion is a better user experience.

Comment: i didnt understand george suggestion xD... and i want to design the confirm way with the bootstrap. how do i use that :S?

Comment: Check out the ui.bootstrap.modal link.  You can make the buttons be confirm or deny and design the html for the modal however you like.  Here is a SO question with a solid example of how to create what you're looking for: [reusable modal service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29602222/create-a-simple-bootstrap-yes-no-confirmation-or-just-notification-alert-in-angu)

Comment: i dont know why i cant understand that.. im using this guide: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_modal.asp | https://prnt.sc/k67ypc | but when i press DELETE the screen turns grey and i cant press anything : http://prntscr.com/k67yrw help? my code is :

Comment: http://prntscr.com/k67zc4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the function as below using confirm function in which you can enter any message that will prompt user

```
$scope.RemoveWorker=function(workerid){
    if(confirm("Do you really want to delete this record ?")){
        $http.delete("/ShiftWeb/rest/admin/removeworker?id="+workerid)
             .then(function(response){$scope.removeworker=response.data;
               alert("Worker " + workerid + " Deleted");
               $state.reload()
              console.log(response.data);
              }, function(error) {
                    alert(error.data);
             });
     }
};
```

Comment: Starting with Chrome 46.0 this method is blocked inside an `<iframe>` unless it sandbox attribute has the value `allow-modal`. Be sure to review the notes in [MDN Web API Reference - Window.confirm()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm).

Comment: how do i use the attribute value? allow-modal?